# RoR. Creating records in rails console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, records, nameerror

Hello i'm a beginner following the Lynda ruby on rails tutorial.

Here is the code I have to run subject = Subject.new. but everytime i type that into the rails console, I get this error.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Subject
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It appears you have not defined the class `Subject`.

Comment: How would i go by defining that? I'm very new to this

Comment: Create a model or scaffolding? How did the tutorial create it?

Comment: You are asking how one defines a class. That's a different question, one that you should answer by doing some basic research.

Answer (score 0):

new is a method of Class. With your code

```
subject = Subject.new
```

you want to create an instance of the class Subject, but you it seems that you haven't defined a class Subject.

On irb you can do it this way:

```
class Subject
end
```

and now with

```
subject = Subject.new
```

you can create an instance of Subject, what you can test with

```
subject.class
=> #<Subject:0x007fca538325c8>
```

But this all makes not much sense if you haven't defined any methods for the class Subject. And this is all is essential ruby or essential OOP, so try to get some basic stuff about Ruby. I suggest [Rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/) or something else.